# Get custom QNetworkRequest object from QNetworkReply

Tags: qt, inheritance, qnetworkrequest, qnetworkreply

Here's the code I've got:

```
UserInfoRequest request(token);
QNetworkReply* reply = network->sendCustomRequest(request, request.getVerb());
```

Where UserInfoRequest derives from another class:

```
class APIRequest : public QNetworkRequest
```

So the question is: can I somehow cast `QNetworkRequest` object which was returned by `QNetworkReply::request()` to my `APIRequest` class? If it is impossible, then what is the best way to pass my custom request object from 
code listed before to reply handler slot.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good idea to assign a base class to a derived one. That's because `APIRequest` has everything belonging to `QNetworkReply` but `QNetworkReply` does not contain some extra features of `APIRequest`. So when you assign `QNetworkReply` to `APIRequest`, the assignment operator of `QNetworkReply` is used and al of the extra data of `APIRequest` remains untouched.

In case you really want want to do this, you should have an assignment operator like:

```
class APIRequest : public QNetworkReply 
{
    APIRequest& operator= (const QNetworkReply& reply) 
    { 
       ... 
    }
}
```

In which you copy members of `QNetworkReply` and somehow deal with the extra information in the derived type `APIRequest`. Then you can directly assign `QNetworkReply::request()` to an object of `APIRequest`.